# Get thumbnail of the recorded video to show on next screen

Tags: android, thumbnails

I recorded a video(not using intent) and i want to get the thumbnail of that specific video (sdcard/myfolder/sample.mp4) to show on the next screen/activity oncreate.I i try to get thumbnail in next activity, app crashes.
If i dont try to get thumbnail and just pass the video path to videoView of the next activity, It goes to next screen and the video starts playing. 
I want to record video, show thumbnail of that video on next screen, when thumbnail is clicked it plays the video.

I tried these two ways in the activity after the recording:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    String filename = extras.getString("playfile");

    Bitmap tmb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filename,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    imgview.setImageBitmap(tmb);
```

The app crashes.

when i try this:

```
   Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    String filename = extras.getString("playfile");

    mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoPath(filename);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

App doesn't crash and plays video. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured why it was crashing.
In my camera activity i didnt destroy the surface properly.

This fixed it:

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.lock();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
```

Hope it helps.